# Unable to compile an old Androdi Studio project in the latest Version

Tags: android

I have a free App, up in the Play Store.

I have not made any changes nor have I recompiled it for over two years. As such it has now be delisted until I at least compile it Again targeting newer SDKs. So that It can appear again.

The previous android studio was in another computer so I had to do a fresh install (Android Studio Jiraffe).

Once I finished, I just imported the old project.

So I have directory for the old project. I have deleted all gradle related files
So basically the only project files are

```
app
build
```

I then I simply opened the project with girffe. I had no errors that I could see.

However I'm unable to even attempt to create a signed bundle as the option is not there.

For example when I try to run it I get "Module Not Specified"

If I select the module and hit make module I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Each request requires the same not null build mode to be set
```

And this notification

```
Unable to find Gradle tasks to build: [:]. Build mode: COMPILE_JAVA. Tests: All.
```

So. All I want to do is compile my app and code.

How can I do this?

Comment: Old Android projects usually require Java 8, not 17. Install JDK 8 and set it as Java runtime for Gradle in AS, or simply open a console/terminal cd to the project dir, set `JAVA_HOME` env variable to the JDK 8 directory and execute `./gradlew assemblerelease`.

Comment: I'm confident that using newer Java won't break anything. Is there a way that I can change the project to use Java 17 in a simple manner?

Comment: It is obvious that you don't do Java development. Every Java version after 8 had a lot of breaking changes. Even Gradle itself has a [compatibility matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html) which Gradle version is compatible with which JRE/JDK version. And in addition also the used Gradle plugins (like Android Gradle Plugin) are not compatible with every Java version.